# redis causes errors in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, redis, phpmyadmin, settings

Today I have a problem with phpmyadmin and redis, meaning that when I try to view the phpmyadmin management page the following error appears:
phpMyAdmin - Error

```
Error during session start; please check your PHP and / or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
session_start (): Cannot find save handler 'redis' - session startup failed.
```

Note that if I go to the terminal, and do the command redis-cli everything works perfectly.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I'd start by checking the webserver error log to see if there are further details, also looking at the redis logs for hints. Check the path used for writing session data, make sure it exists and has enough free space.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? I have the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
The problem was here in the php.ini file.
I had to copy the following into the php.ini file:

```
session.save_path= "tcp://host1:6379?weight=1, tcp://host2:6379?weight=2&timeout=2.5, tcp://host3:6379?weight=2&read_timeout=2.5"
```

The solution was to replace **host1**, **host2**, and **host3** with localhost:

```
session.save_path= "tcp://localhost:6379?weight=1, tcp://localhost:6379?weight=2&timeout=2.5, tcp://localhost:6379?weight=2&read_timeout=2.5"
```

Comment: If you have just _one_ server, what's the benefit of placing 3 different accesses (especially with different weights!) to Redis? You should be more than fine with the default, e.g. just `session.save_path= "tcp://localhost:6379"` (assuming no password)